# Python escapes backslash in raw string

Tags: python

I want to use latex in my plots with matplotlib. So far, that's working out -- but now a backslash makes things difficult.

Here's what I tried:

```
r'$a_{{\text{{test}}}}$ ({})'.format('foo')
Out[13]: '$a_{\\text{test}}$ (foo)'
```

But my expected output is

```
'$a_{\text{test}}$ (foo)'
```

I've tried a lot of messing with this, but to no avail: Escaping the backslash in raw environment naturally creates 4 of them. How do I get the expected, single backslash?

---

What fundamentally is not working is plotting this in matplotlib

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.plot(np.array([1, 1]), label=r'$a_{{\text{{test}}}}$ ({})'.format('foo'))
plt.legend()
```

which leads to the following error:

```
RuntimeError: latex was not able to process the following string:
b'$a_{\\\\text{test}}$ (foo)'
Here is the full report generated by latex:
This is pdfTeX, Version 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.18 (TeX Live 2017/Debian) (preloaded format=latex)
 restricted \write18 enabled.
entering extended mode
(/home/saman/.cache/matplotlib/tex.cache/3d4d47cda002ea7b54e89aca2a4b3fae.tex
LaTeX2e <2017-04-15>
Babel <3.18> and hyphenation patterns for 84 language(s) loaded.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/article.cls
Document Class: article 2014/09/29 v1.4h Standard LaTeX document class
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/size10.clo))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/type1cm/type1cm.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/helvet.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/graphics/keyval.sty))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/textcomp.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1enc.def))
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/geometry/geometry.sty
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifpdf.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/oberdiek/ifvtex.sty)
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/generic/ifxetex/ifxetex.sty)
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `h'-direction.
    `width' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
Package geometry Warning: Over-specification in `v'-direction.
    `height' (5058.9pt) is ignored.
)
No file 3d4d47cda002ea7b54e89aca2a4b3fae.aux.
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/base/ts1cmr.fd)
*geometry* driver: auto-detecting
*geometry* detected driver: dvips
(/usr/share/texlive/texmf-dist/tex/latex/psnfss/ot1phv.fd)
! Undefined control sequence.
l.13 ...{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily $a_{\text
                                                  {test}}$ (foo)}
No pages of output.
Transcript written on 3d4d47cda002ea7b54e89aca2a4b3fae.log.
```

Comment: The error you get is that `\text` is not defined, and indeed, it's not defined (you did not call for `amsmath`). Perhaps you wanted `\mathrm` or `\textnormal`. See also https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/98406/95042

Comment: @torek Indeed that's the answer, and its worthy of being formulated as one :)

Answer (score 0):

Once you format is not raw. The output is ok.
Try storing that into a variable and then print it.

```
s = r"\{}"
print(s)
res = s.format("foo")
print(res)
```

Comment: Alternatively, you can use `r'string'.decode('string_escape')`.

Comment: Ive updated the question since you suggest that the output is ok: All in all, matplotlib does not like the string, so that's why I tried debugging it the way i was.

Comment: @FooBar, something is wrong in latex then. did you notice the output? `l.13 ...{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily $a_{\text
                                                  {test}}$ (foo)}`, is this correct?=

Answer (score 0):

You only have a single backslash. I don't know how you're looking at your string, but the output is in not-raw string notation, which is why you see `\\`. But that's just for demonstration purposes. For example, the output also shows single quotes (`'...'`), which aren't really part of your string either.

Try `print(r'$a_{{\text{{test}}}}$ ({})'.format('foo'))`.

Comment: Ive updated the question since you suggest that the output is ok: All in all, matplotlib does not like the string, so that's why I tried debugging it the way i was.

Comment: @FooBar The LaTeX error `l.13 ...{10.000000}{12.500000}{\sffamily $a_{\text
                                                  {test}}$ (foo)}` shows that it really is `\text{test}`. There's something else wrong (e.g. is `\text{...}` actually valid LaTeX?).

Comment: Outside of python, `$a_{\text{test}}$ (foo)` compiles fine directly in latex. Do you suggest I open a new question focussing matplotlib?

Comment: @FooBar That would make sense, yes.